# A lot of my file system space has disappeared. Where is it?

Tags: disk-usage

I have allocated an 84GB partition for Ubuntu.  Disk utility and Gparted confirm this.  But disk usage analyzer can account for only about 24GB of used space, and I get a warning telling my the file system is down to only 4GB of space.  Is there some kind of process that hides used space from the disk usage analyzer and from my file browser?  I have set file browsing options to show hidden files -- I think.  Do I have to set this in EVERY directory?  I doubt it, but hey, SOMETHING is using space and I can't account for it.  Where and how do I look for this missing space?

```
dad@Dad-Stubuntu:~$ df -h  
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda2              77G   68G  5.8G  93% /  
none                  5.8G  856K  5.8G   1% /dev  
none                  5.8G  1.8M  5.8G   1% /dev/shm  
none                  5.8G  472K  5.8G   1% /var/run  
none                  5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /var/lock  
/dev/sdc3             1.3T  104G  1.2T   8% /media/WinWork  
/dev/sdc4             1.3T  547G  682G  45% /media/LinWork  
/dev/sr2               24M   24M     0 100% /media/WD Unlocker  
/dev/sdf1             932G  853G   79G  92% /media/My Book__  
/dev/sdm1             1.9T  1.9T  5.5G 100% /media/My Book  
/dev/sdb3              79G   66G   13G  84% /media/Win7-P1  
/dev/sdb5             118G   60G   58G  51% /media/Win7-P2  
/dev/sdb6             108G   70G   39G  65% /media/Win7-P3  
/dev/sdb1              79G   77G  1.8G  98% /media/Win7  
/dev/sda3              79G   42G   37G  54% /media/Win-8  
/dev/sda1              79G   29G   50G  37% /media/Win-XP  
/dev/sda7             112G  104G  8.6G  93% /media/WinXP-P3  
/dev/sdk1             932G  926G  6.3G 100% /media/My Book_  
/dev/sdn1             1.4T  1.2T  182G  88% /media/Elements  



dad@Dad-Stubuntu:~$ df -h /boot  
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda2              77G   68G  5.8G  93% /
```

When I get file or directory properties, and also dusk usage analyzer doesn't come close to identifying that much used space.  I will try it as sudo.

`sudo baobab` tells me that `/root/.local/share/Trash/files` is using 46.4 GB.

This could be my missing space.  Why can't I see this in my file browser?

If I do `gksudo nautilus` will I see my lost space in the file broswer?
Also, I have included "delete" option in file menu and it is supposed to not
put it in trash.  Why is so much in Trash?

OK, thanks to Charles Green and xen2050 I found and freed my missing space.  I did `sudo nautilus` and followed the path to `/root/.local/share/Trash/` and in each of the directories I deleted (I added the "delete" option as root) all the files and now have 56GB free space.  Thank you sirs.

Comment: Often the system is indicating that the /boot directory is full.  Can you issue the commands `df -h` and `df -h /boot`, and post the results to the end of your question?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that all the time, "where'd all the space go?" GNOME disk usage analyzer (baobab) usually works great for seeing what's big & what's where, but normally it's run as your user, and it sounds like there's hidden files that you can't see, you could try running baobab as root (`sudo baobab`) and then take a look?

Or your filesystem(s) could need `fsck` maybe the free space count is wrong or something.

Or maybe your `/` or home filesystem is on a very small partition that is almost full, while another partition has gigs and gigs of free space? I think the "low space" warning only comes up for `/` and/or your home?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're low enough on disk space that linux is using special reserved space.  Programs will act funny until you give them some normal space to use, Disk Usage Analyzer included.  I think I remember seeing the exact same thing a while ago.